# Python + Selenium(Chrome): Expansion timeout on slow computers

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, timeout, renderer

I'm trying to load an extension(Metamask) into chrome to do some automated stuff. It works just fine on on my gaming grade rig, but both my laptop as well as my technical outdated homeserver pc timeout:

> ```
>  opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
>  opt.binary_location = self.chrome_exe_location
>  opt.add_argument('--log-level=3')
>  opt.add_argument('--start-maximized')
>  opt.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])        
>  opt.add_extension(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '10.9.3_0.crx'))
>
>  self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.chromedriver_exe_location, options=opt, service_args='')
> ```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\OneDrive\CloudDesktop\Python\main.py", line 968, in
>
> bot()   File "C:\OneDrive\CloudDesktop\Python\main.py", line 69, in
> **init**
> self.chrome_initialize()   File "C:\OneDrive\CloudDesktop\Python\main.py", line 118, in
> chrome_initialize
> self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.chromedriver_exe_location, options=opt, service_args='')   File
> "C:\OneDrive\CloudDesktop\Python\vEnv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py",
> line 70, in **init**
> super(WebDriver, self).**init**(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
> File
> "C:\OneDrive\CloudDesktop\Python\vEnv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 93, in **init**
> RemoteWebDriver.**init**(   File "C:\OneDrive\CloudDesktop\Python\vEnv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 269, in **init**
> self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)   File "C:\OneDrive\CloudDesktop\Python\vEnv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 360, in start_session
> response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)   File "C:\OneDrive\CloudDesktop\Python\vEnv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 425, in execute
> self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\OneDrive\CloudDesktop\Python\vEnv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
> line 247, in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
> failed to wait for extension background page to load:
> chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background.html
> from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000

- Chrome and chromedriver versions 98.0.4758.102 64bit on all computers
- Python versions 3.10.1(one pc working and one desn't) and 3.10.2(not
  working)
- OS: Win 10(none working) and 11(working) all updated
- CPU:5600x(working), Snapdragon 8cx(not working),Intel Celeron J3455(not working)

I guess this timeout occurs because selenium does not wait until the expansion is fully loaded or transferred. The .crx is about 18MB in size and I'd say the computer on which it's working takes about 5 secs and both other ones about 30 secs.

I already tinkered with selenium timeouts, but I found it's a lost cause, because I really can just set these parameters after the selenium object is created, which causes this timeout in the first place.

Does anyone of you guys know a way how selenium allows the startup process some more time?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In the official Google Chrome support for chromedriver, there were some suggestions to use `options.add_experimental_option('extensionLoadTimeout', 60000)`.
The time specified is in milliseconds, so 60 thousand corresponds to a timeout of one minute. This fixes timeout problems for slow PCs.

Comment: When I add that line, I get "unrecognized chrome option: extensionLoadTimeout". Is this solution still viable?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

1. Download extension in a normal use instance of chrome.
2. chrome://version/ copy profile path
   e.g. C:\Users\pcuser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
3. Python code:

   ```
    profile_path = r'C:\\Users\\pcuser\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data'
    opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir={}'.format(profile_path)) # profile path
    opt.add_argument('--profile-directory={}'.format('DEFAULT')) #profile name
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.chromedriver_exe_location, options=opt, service_args='')
    self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(60) # adapt as you see fit
    self.driver.set_script_timeout(60) # adapt as you see fit
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(60) # adapt as you see fit
   ```